# Please how to solve NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-urls

Reverse for `student_detail` with keyword arguments `{'student_id': 'STUD/1/230922'}` not found.

```
1 pattern(s) tried: ['students/STUD/(?P<student_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<current_date>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

- this is how I set my urls.py

```py
path('STUD/<int:student_id>/<int:current_date>/', views.StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='student_detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only student ID, while in `urls.py` the URL path has date (as int) as well.
Try passing something like:

```
{
'student_id': 1, 
'current_date': 230922
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Daniel's answer didn't solve the problem then I guess the problem is with `STUD/1/230922` because it has many slashes and slashes are used to identify paths. so try removing the slashes in the student Id and see if it works.